# Getting player alias

Tags: objective-c, ios, gamekit

I have a GKTurnBasedMatch named currentMatch, and I would like to know how to get the name of the player who plays after the player that is currently playing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *playerIDs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:match.participants.count];
for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *part in match.participants) {
    if([part.playerID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        [playerIDs addObject:part.playerID];
    }
}


[GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
    for (GKPlayer *player in players) {

       //get the aliases
}


}];
```